# WebSocket QML Type is there a ping/pong system

Tags: qt, websocket, qml, qtwebsockets

Does [WebSocket QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocket.html) support any ping/pong system?

Documentation doesn't say anything about it, so I'm wondering if there is a way to "simulate" `ping/pong`, e.g. trying to use one of the `send` methods and check what comes back in the co-responding `received` signal?

Or should I use [QWebSocket Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html) to implement it?
Also would it be bad practice to keep the `QML WebSocket` for send/receive functionality, while using the class just for ping/pong purpose, so better just implement whole functionality in the class?

Comment: What do you mean saying `ping-pong system`? If all you want is to just send something and receive response so `WebSocket` has ` sendTextMessage` function and `textMessageReceived` signal.

Comment: I mean ping-pong system that occasionally, well, pings the server to see if the connection is still up. I haven't done much with websockets before (besides send normal text messages), but if I'm not mistaken, it's different from a normal send message, which can be seen in the class documentation. Maybe the normal send message works to, but I'd rather make sure than make a bad implementation.